# Unable to write to HDFS as non sudo user

Tags: hadoop

I've changed the permission of a hdfs directory via

```
hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /path/to/dir
```

but, when writing to that directory as a non-sudo user, i get a permission error

`Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=crtemois, access=WRITE, inode="/aggregation/system/data/clean":owners:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Apache Ranger was layered on top. Even though the permissions were changed via `chmod 777`, if the user permission wasn't set in Apache Ranger, writing wouldn't be possible.